# Assign values to keys

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, keymap

How to assign my email address to a key combination (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>) so that I do not have to repeatedly type the address?

The operating system is Windows Vista Home Premium.

Answer (score 4):

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) was -made- for this.

```
^F10::Send address@example.org
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows7 you may make a shortcut for the url on your desktop, right click on the desktop icon. Thereafter you click onto properties, in the window that shows up, it should say hotkeys further down in the window. Here you can set hotkeys for it, should work for all shortcut icons, it may not work in vista, but its highly unlikely that it wont work.